# When does limit equal to infinity exist/not exist?

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I do not understand why limits equal to infinity can in certain circumstances exist while in others they do not.

For instance, the limit does not exist for the following:
[image: lim 1]

However, I believe the limit is equal to $-\infty$ in this case: [image: lim 2]

Why??? Why is limit 2 a special case? I don't understand.
Is it because it can be simplified using long division?

Help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think the limit exists in both cases.

Comment: then im very confused, because I have been answering DNE for questions like the first limit shown and getting them correct.

Comment: Think of it like, infinity being so large that the terms of smaller powers being insignificant. In the first case, the term in the numerator is x, and the denominator would be $x^{\frac{2}{3}}$ since we ignore the 5 terms since it is basically irrelevant compared to infinity. Since the top term is larger, this converges to infinity, which is the same as if you plug this into a graphing calculator.

Comment: The limit does not exist in either case. Instead of saying the limit doesn't exist as in the limit of the sine function when its argument approaches infinity, we find it useful to discuss the asymptotic behavior of a function. In other words, we sometimes want to know if the limit doesn't exist because the function gets arbitrarily large as in $\infty$ or arbitrarily small as in $-\infty$. Although this gives us useful information about the function, the limit does not exist in either case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that "the limit is equal to $-\infty$" is not a precise statement, or rather that the function approaching $-\infty$ in the tail does NOT mean the limit exists - for the limit to exist it can only be a real number.

The limit does not exist in either example above. While it's still not absolutely precise it is common to say "approaches infinity" to mean grows in an unbounded fashion - there are other ways for a limit to not exist, e.g. a sequence that bounces back and forth between two values.

The way to evaluate these quickly (without formal proof, although this reasoning can be justified) is just to compare highest powers in the numerator and denominator, and constants can be ignored (except in the case where the highest powers agree).

The first example has the same tail behavior as $\frac x{x^{2/3}} = \sqrt[3]{x}$ which approaches $+\infty$ and the second behaves like $\frac {x^2}x = x$ which approaches $-\infty$.

Comment: Did you already take a real analysis class or a general topology class? This is where one typically learns the definition of a 2-point compactification of the real line and the corresponding notions of infinite limits (as well as limits in general topological spaces).

Comment: @MoisheKohan good points; though it was pretty clear the OP is asking in the context of limits as seen in basic calculus (and my answer was predicated on that). You should add more detail on how the answers change in those spaces.

Comment: Yes, even though this answer does agree with my understanding and is helpful, it seems my class has a specific definition of a limit, or is expecting certain answers, whether it be DNE or +/-∞, in certain contexts. It appears limit questions of a rational expression where the numerator is exactly one degree greater than the denominator need to be answered differently (i.e +/-∞, instead of DNE). However, this also doesn't seem consistent. This may be a case of bad online homework.

Comment: That is perfectly fine in this context.  The "values" $\pm\infty$ can serve as answers that are a little more refined than "DNE" as long as what they mean is understood - the functions approach them (are unbounded in that direction) and that they are NOT real numbers even though treating them as such *sometimes* works.